# What tutorials would you like to see about using Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm working on some more tutorials for http://backbonetutorials.com and interested in what the community would like researched and discussed.

Comment: You may want to post it in programmers.stackexchange(?)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what is the difference? I'm not too familiar with this place @geekam

Comment: @ThomasDavis, the tutorials on there right now are a great help! I'd like to see more about handling transitions from one route to another - how to remove old views (in such a way that they get garbage collected), how to add new views, and how to handle full page layouts and transitions between a "page" to a "page" - in a single page app.

Comment: @swatkins I definitely have a lot of insight into that and have noted it down. Could I ask that future comments be posted as a new answer so I can manage it easier.

Comment: @ThomasDavis - This question will probably get closed or moved from here. Stack Overflow is pretty good at keeping the questions to something that doesn't require debate - answers should be factual and not require too much discussion. As geekam said, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for this type of question, although it wouldn't receive as much traffic.

Answer (score 3):

I like your tutorials and I found them useful but a bit unlinked one to another. I think best tutorials are those that cover a complete real-world-like example. I suggest you:

- find an example application to build
- glue together your tutorials
- and show how build the app with backbone.js